# SSRS Pull data from last year when January

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

Basically, when the report is run, I'd like to display YTD data; **unless**, it is January, then, I want to display all of last year.

I've been attempting to put this in my where statement, using case or iif. In both cases, I get the same error: *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1... Incorrect syntax near 'between'.*

```
SELECT      
name,
owner,
duedate,
submitteddate   
FROM Table
WHERE submitteddate IS NOT NULL AND
CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1
THEN submitteddate between  DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 1 , '19000101') AND DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101'))))
ELSE submitteddate between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND  GETDATE()))
end
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

It seems like related to usage of the bracelets. please try like below:

```
SELECT      
name,
owner,
duedate,
submitteddate   
FROM Table
WHERE submitteddate IS NOT NULL AND
CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1
THEN submitteddate between  DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 1 , '19000101') AND DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101'))
ELSE submitteddate between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND  GETDATE()
end
```

Comment: This won't work; the `CASE` expression doesn't create a full boolean expression. In a `WHERE` clause you can't have `CASE WHEN {expression} THEN {Boolean Expression} ELSE {Boolean Expression} END` and not follow it without a boolean operator and further expression. Just like every other clause it has to be in the format `{CASE Expression} = {Expression}` (of course, you can replace `=` with `!=`, `>`,`<`, `IN`, or any other boolean operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
....WHERE YEAR(submitteddate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                  - CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE`, which isn't SARGable, you would be far better off using variables:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate Date;

SET @StartDate = CASE DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,GETDATE())-1,0)
                                                ELSE DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()),0)
                 END;
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,@StartDate)+1,0);

--SELECT @StartDate, @EndDate; --Uncomment to check the values, but would break SSRS, as it only reads the first returned dataset.

SELECT [name],
       [owner],
       duedate,
       submitteddate   
FROM [Table]
WHERE submitteddate >= @StartDate
  AND submitteddate < @EndDate;
```

Note that there is no need to check if the value of `submitteddate` is `NULL` or not. `NULL = {expression}` will always result in "unknown", which isn't true and thus won't be returned in a data set. Thus if you don't want `NULL` values, then the `IS NOT NULL` clause is pointless in a `WHERE` like:

```
WHERE [Column] IS NOT NULL
  AND [Column] = 1;
```

The above would return exactly the same rows as:

```
WHERE [Column] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
WHERE 
      submitteddate >=
      IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, DATEADD(Year, -1, GETDATE()), '1900-01-01')
      AND submitteddate <= GETDATE();
```

Or by using a variable

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATEIME = (SELECT IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, DATEADD(Year, -1, GETDATE()), '1900-01-01'));

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
      submitteddate >=
      @FromDate
      AND submitteddate <= GETDATE();
```

Comment: Neither of these would give the right result in January. If, for example, today was 2019-01-31 then the range would be 2018-01-01 to 2019-01-31. That's 13 months of data, not all of last year's.

Comment: @Larnu `SELECT DATEADD(Year, -1,'2019-01-31')` give `2018-01-31 00:00:00` not 2018-01-01, so in the where it would be between 2018-01-31 and 2019-01-31

Comment: `submitteddate BETWEEN
      @FromDate
      AND GETDATE();` If today is `20190131` then `GETDATE()` will return `20190131`. the OP States *" it is January, then, I want to display all of last year."* not "it is January then I want to display all of last year to date".